# Not able to install signature keys 

Tags: blackberry, key, signature

I have to sign a BlackBerry application so that I can load it onto the device, but the system that the signature keys I got from RIM are installed on got formatted.  Now I am trying to install the signature keys on another system, but the server prompts me for this:
"Unable to register client '2909103544' because there are no more registration attempts.  If you have already registered with this server, then you must contact RIM to register additional user."

Can we install these keys on only one single computer?  Do I now have to purchase new keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to re purchase the keys, since they are for single developer, single pc

Comment: Thanks Reflog,
i tried to install the keys on the same system on which these are previously  installed. Since the system gets formatted i tired to install the keys but the same message prompts me.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way around it. If you formatted the system without recovering the installed keys, you cannot use the CSI files to install them again, you'll have to get new keys.

Comment: Thanks Reflog , Can i request them (RIM) to reactivate my keys

Comment: I am not sure, you will have to contact their support team.

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry JDE Plug-in for Eclipse Users:

1. Save all 3 .csi files in the same directory (each one will be sent in a separate email message).
2. Start Eclipse.
3. Click on the BlackBerry menu and choose Install Signature Keys.
4. Select one of the 3 .csi files saved in step 1 and click Open.
5. Click "Yes" to create a new key pair file.
6. Type a password for your private key of at least 8 characters, and type it again to confirm. This is your private key password, which protects your private key. Please remember this password as you will be prompted for it each time signing is attempted or a signature key is installed.
7. Move your mouse to generate date for a new private key.
8. In the Registration PIN" field, type the PIN number that you supplied on the signature key order form.
9. In the Private Key password field, type the password created in step 6.
10. Click Register .
11. Click Exit .
12. Repeat this process for the other csi files.