# running blackberry app on device 'attempts to access a secure api'

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry

I'm new to Blackberry development and need some direction on distributing an app to a device. These are the steps I have taken and where I hit my problem:

- I build my app in eclipse
- In the top menu i go to 'blackberry' > ' sign' > 'sign with signature tool'
- When the signature tool pops up a click 'add' select the cod file in the build
- click 'request' i then see in green 'signed' next to my cod file with the signerid as RBB
- I then use cmd to upload my app using C:\Java>JavaLoader.exe -u load myapp.cod
- the app shows on the phone but after i click on it i get an error 'attempts to access a secure api'

Im suspecting i should have 'signed' against my app for RCR and RRT. What must i do to get this to say signed?

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Go to the link [Install Signature keys][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955155/not-able-to-install-signature-keys/10909525#10909525

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install the three code signing keys on your eclipse.
BlackBerry JDE Plug-in for Eclipse Users:

```
Save all 3 .csi files in the same directory (each one will be sent in a separate email message).
Start Eclipse.
Click on the BlackBerry menu and choose Install Signature Keys.
Select one of the 3 .csi files saved in step 1 and click Open.
Click "Yes" to create a new key pair file.
Type a password for your private key of at least 8 characters, and type it again to confirm. This is your private key password, which protects your private key. Please remember this password as you will be prompted for it each time signing is attempted or a signature key is installed.
Move your mouse to generate date for a new private key.
In the Registration PIN" field, type the PIN number that you supplied on the signature key order form.
In the Private Key password field, type the password created in step 6.
Click Register .
Click Exit .
Repeat this process for the other csi files.
```

Then right click your Project -> **Blackberry** -> **Sign with Signature Tool** , then it will prompt for password. After giving the password, it will sign all your necessary files. After Complete Sign it will show the location of your signed Cod file's location in the Console of eclipse.

Comment: hi signare, I have followed these steps, the cod i use is the one that gets shown in the console for eclipse

Comment: extract the .COD file along with the .jad file in to a folder. then put it on a server. then access the .jad file from your mobile's browser, then it will automatically installed.

Comment: all 3 .csi files arrive in different emails